# how we can detect seperate text for a text multiligue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I have a text ( in english and frensh) in input : i want to seperate the text into two sub-text for each language : so , we will detect the languages in text (> 2 languages) , then , cut each text in his own language:

INPUT :

```
You will then discover galleries in which 25-million bottles rest in the cellars, waiting for the 
perfect moment to be tasted. From the bottle to the salmanazar, from the youngest wines to the oldest   
vintages. - Vous trouverez alors des galeries parmi lesquelles 25 000 000 bouteilles reposent dans les   
caves, attendant le parfait moment pour être dégustées.
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
This text contains two languages : "fr" and "en"

text_in_english= "You will then discover galleries in which 25-million bottles rest in the cellars,  
waiting for the perfect moment to be tasted. From the bottle to the salmanazar, from the youngest  
wines to the oldest vintages."

text_in_frensh= "- Vous trouverez alors des galeries parmi lesquelles 25 000 000 bouteilles reposent 
dans les caves, attendant le parfait moment pour être dégustées."
```

How we can do this please ?

Comment: I think your question has little to do with spacy. If I were you, I would google for language detection, then split text into sentences (with spacy if you insist), and detect language per sentence.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using nltk (uncomment to download punkt if you need it) and langid. Steps are:

```
1. Split the text into sentences  
2. Predict the language of each sentence  
3. Add the predicted sentences to a dictionary to group them by language, in order.
```

python3:

```
from langid import classify
from nltk import tokenize
import nltk
from collections import defaultdict
#nltk.download('punkt')

mytext = """
You will then discover galleries in which 25-million bottles rest in the cellars, waiting for the 
perfect moment to be tasted. From the bottle to the salmanazar, from the youngest wines to the oldest 
vintages. - Vous trouverez alors des galeries parmi lesquelles 25 000 000 bouteilles reposent dans les 
caves, attendant le parfait moment pour être dégustées.
"""
mytext = mytext.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '')
sentences = tokenize.sent_tokenize(mytext)
languages = defaultdict(list)

for sentence in sentences:
    languages[str(classify(sentence)[0])].append(sentence)

for k,v in languages.items():
    print(k,v)
#en [' You will then discover galleries in which 25-million bottles rest in the cellars, waiting for the  perfect moment to be tasted.', 'From the bottle to the salmanazar, from the youngest wines to the oldest  vintages.']   
#fr ['- Vous trouverez alors des galeries parmi lesquelles 25 000 000 bouteilles reposent dans les  caves, attendant le parfait moment pour être dégustées.']
```

Comment: The problem is that  sometimes we have , "sentences in english"-"sentences in frensh".. 
sometimes we have : {-; , ; . %, } between the two language

Comment: no problem, simply add those to the line "mytext.replace()" , or try using nltk to clean the text in more advanced ways.